# DatePickerAndroid open method not working and DatePicker doesn't open on clicking in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-datepicker

I am using the DatePickerAndroid from @react-native-community/datetimepicker in my React Native application. However, I am facing an issue where the open method is not working as expected and the DatePicker doesn’t open when I click on the TextInput.

Here is the code snippet for the DatePicker component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import DatePickerAndroid from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';


export default class DatePicker extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            dateV: props.value ? props.value : null
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.value) {
            this.setState({ dateV: nextProps.value})
        }
    }

    render() {
        let { placeholder } = this.props;
        return(
            <View style={[{ margin: 0 }, this.context.fieldGroupStyle ]}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPress={this.showPicker.bind(this, 'max', {date: this.state.dateV.date})}>
                    // my code
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>
        )
    }

    showPicker = async function (stateKey, options) {
        try {
            var newState = {};
            const {action, year, month, day} = await DatePickerAndroid.open(options);
            if(action === DatePickerAndroid.dismissedAction) {return;}
            var now = new Date();
            var date = new Date(year, month, day, now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());
            newState[stateKey + 'Text'] = formatDate(date, this.props.format);
            newState[stateKey + 'Date'] = date;
            this.props.onChange({ date: newState.maxDate, text: newState.maxText });
        } catch ({code, message}) {
            console.warn(`Error in '${stateKey}': `, message);
        }
    };
}
```

When I try to open the date picker by clicking on the TextInput, it does not open and I do see errors in catch block which says `Error in max, undefined is not a function` . Please help me with a fix

I tried using ComponentDidUpdate instead of componentWillReceiveProps but nothing worked. The date picker only doesn't open.

My dateV from state is

> {"date": "2023-08-16T18:30:00.000Z" , "text": "Wednesday, August 16,
> 2023"}